# Como inicializar uma lista de listas vazias?

Tags: python, lista, python-2.7

Usando Python 2.7.12

Estou precisando criar uma lista da seguinte forma:

```
lista = [[],[],[],[],.........,[]]
```

Essa lista precisa ter um número bem grande de listas dentro dela (por isso os ........). Achei por aí a seguinte forma de realizar isso:

```
lista = [[]]*n
```

Onde "n" é o número de sub-listas. Só que com isso eu chego a um problema. Abaixo segue um exemplo (com um número de sub-listas bem menor para ilustração).

```
lista = [[]]*3
lista[0].append(1)
lista[1].append(2)
print lista
```

A saída deveria ser:

```
[[1], [2], []]
```

Mas a saída desse código é:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Não tenho a mínima ideia do que seja, nem conheço/achei outra forma de criar um lista desse tipo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O problema do código que tentou fazer:

```
lista = [[]]*n
```

É que o objeto que será repetido, `[]`, é inicializado apenas uma vez, quando definida sua referência e essa é utilizada nas outras posições. Para demonstrar isso, basta percorrer a lista e exibir o valor de `id`:

```
lista = [[]]*3

for l in lista:
    print id(l)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/RigidPossibleLanguage) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/IFDShP) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/a3c61652d89859a1e5c7df004d899a38)</sup>

Os três valores serão os mesmos, tal como em:

```
47056207983464
47056207983464
47056207983464
```

Para demonstrar melhor o que acontece, basta verificar o *opcode* executado, com auxílio do módulo `dis`:

```
>>> print dis.dis('[[]]*3')
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 BUILD_LIST               1
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (3)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Veja que a operação `BUILD_LIST` é executada duas vezes, uma para a lista interna e outra para a externa; posteriormente é carregado a constante 3 e é feito a multiplicação entre os valores. Ou seja, é criada apenas uma referência para a lista interna, que é multiplicada por 3.

Para contornar este problema, você pode utilizar a *list comprehension*:

```
lista = [[] for _ in xrange(n)]
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/NimbleEnchantedGames) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/YwbaQP) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/9fc218e9861ff58f8162b55038aa71a9)</sup>

Assim, `n` referências distintas são definidas.

> Para a mesma solução no Python 3, basta substituir a função `xrange` por `range`.

Isso acontece, inclusive, com todos os tipos mutáveis do Python. Por exemplo, se você possui uma classe `Foo` e quer criar uma lista de instâncias, você não pode fazer:

```
lista = [Foo()]*3
```

Ficando ainda mais claro que `Foo` será instanciada apenas uma vez e o objeto criado que será multiplicado por 3.

Comment: Perfeito! Valeu.

Answer (score 4):

Apenas complementando a [resposta do @Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/298853/6333)...

## Multiplicação de sequências

Na [documentação sobre sequências](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range), a descrição do operador de adição e multiplicação entre sequências e inteiros define o seguinte:

---

*-- Tradução livre das partes relevantes ao problema --*

> Sendo `s` e `t` sequências de mesmo tipo e `n` um número inteiro

- **`s + t`**: a concatenação de `s` e `t`.

  Exemplo:

  ```
  [0, 1, 2] + [3, 4, 5]
  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  ```
- **`s * n`** or **`n * s`**:  equivalente a adicionar `s` com ele mesmo `n` vezes.

  ***Observação***: Os itens da sequência `s` não são copiados, mas sim referenciados múltiplas vezes. <sup>[Nota 2 da documentação]</sup>

  Exemplo:

  ```
  [0] * 3
  # [0, 0, 0]

  # Mesmo que 
  [0] + [0] + [0]
  # [0, 0, 0]
  ```

---

Se você observar a nota 2 na documentação é especificado que os itens das sequências multiplicadas não são copiados, mas sim referenciados (pelo menos os tipos mutáveis, como já explicado na resposta do @Woss e na [documentação do python](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-did-changing-list-y-also-change-list-x)).

Então:

```
s = [[]] * 3
```

Seria o mesmo que criar uma lista vazia e referenciá-la `n` vezes na lista externa:

```
_tmp = []
s = [_tmp, _tmp, _tmp]

print(s)
# [[], [], []]
```

Por consequência modificar `_tmp` refletirá em todos os elementos de `s` já que todos referenciam a mesma lista:

```
s[0].append(1)

print(s)
# [[1], [1], [1]]

_tmp.append(2)

print(x)
# [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

---

## Implementação de id() no CPython

Na [documentação da função `id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) explica que a função retorna a "identidade" de um objeto, onde esta é um número inteiro e é garantido de ser único durante o tempo de vida daquele objeto.

Por fim há uma nota dizendo:

> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory.

Que em tradução livre seria:

> Detalhe de implementação do CPython: Este é o endereço do objeto na memória.

Ou seja, esse é o motivo pelo qual usamos a função [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id), pois é garantido que, se o endereço de memória é o mesmo, as variáveis referenciam o mesmo objeto.

Exemplo:

```
lista = []
print(id(lista))
# 139942416872384

ref = lista
print(id(ref))
# 139942416872384

outra_lista = []
print(id(outra_lista))
# 139942416112048
```

Repare que `lista` e `ref` apontam para o mesmo endereço de memória, e por isso possuem seu `id` iguais, já `outra_lista` é outro objeto em memória. Lembrando que os números acima variam a cada execução do programa, usei apenas para exemplifica.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar a list comprehension:

```
lista = [[] for _ in xrange(n)]
```

https://pythonacademy.com.br/blog/list-comprehensions-no-python

Comment: Jeferson, isso já não foi contemplado nas outras respostas?

Comment: Jeferson, considere ao responder trazer para o autor da resposta um novo ponto de vista ou conhecimento diferente dos já publicados em outras respostas. Caso queira se focar conhecimento já contemplado, mostre o que ainda não foi abordado, explique o por que do foco e quais as vantagens da abordagem sobre as demais e sempre que possível ao responder forneça um [mcve].