# Limite ao criar uma lista no Python

Tags: python

Com o seguinte comando, consigo criar uma lista em Python:

```
lista = [[None]]*50
```

Terei uma lista de listas com 50 unidades. Porém, se eu criar uma lista dessa forma:

```
lista = [[None]]*50

for l in lista:
    l.append([0]*1000)
```

Se eu der `len(lista)` terei como resultado 50, porém se eu der `len(lista[0])` terei o resultado 51 e não 1000. O que está acontecendo? Por que sempre está dando o tamanho total da lista + 1 em vez de 1000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque o que você está adicionando na lista é uma outra lista de 1000 elementos, mas mesmo possuindo 1000 elementos, ela só conta como um - pois é somente uma única lista.

Ao fazer:

```
>>> lista = [[None]]*5
>>> print(lista)
[
    [None], 
    [None], 
    [None], 
    [None], 
    [None]
]
```

Você terá uma lista de 5 objetos, que cada objeto é uma lista com 1 objeto (`None`).

Após, fazendo:

```
>>> for l in lista:
...     l.append([0]*2)
>>> print(lista)
[
    [None, [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], 
    [None, [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], 
    [None, [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], 
    [None, [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], 
    [None, [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
]
```

Que é uma lista de listas com 6 elementos. Está certo, este é o comportamento esperado, mas não é o que você esperava/desejava.

[Listas de listas vazias (Python)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/298851/5878)

Para criar a matriz que precisa, de 50 linhas e 1000 colunas, precisa fazer:

```
lista = [[0 for j in range(1000)] for i in range(50)]
```

Comment: Outro detalhe é que como listas são passadas por referência, todos os elementos da lista são uma referência à mesma lista; experimente `lista[0] is lista[1]` com o código original.

Comment: @PedrovonHertwig Sim, isso está explicado na pergunta que citei