# Por que essas duas formas de inicializar a mesma lista em Python geram estruturas de tamanhos diferentes?

Tags: python, cpython, python-internals

É comum precisarmos inicializar uma lista em Python com uma quantidade definida de elementos e podemos fazer isso de duas maneiras: 1) multiplicando a lista com um elemento pela quantidade desejada; ou 2) utilizar a técnica de *list comprehensions*.

> **Nota:** para objetos mutáveis, [utilize a *list comprehension*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/298853/5878).

**1. Inicializando a lista através da multiplicação**

```
>>> import sys
>>> lista1 = [None]*15
>>> print(lista1)
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> print(sys.getsizeof(lista1))
184
```

**2. Inicializando com *list comprehension***

```
>>> import sys
>>> lista2 = [None for _ in range(15)]
>>> print(lista2)
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> print(sys.getsizeof(lista2))
192
```

Interessante notar que os objetos criados possuem, de fato, o mesmo valor:

```
>>> print(lista1 == lista2)
True
```

Então de onde, e porquê, surgiu essa diferença de 8 bytes entre os objetos? Ambos possuem exatamente a mesma quantidade (15) do mesmo valor (`None`). Não deveriam ter o mesmo tamanho?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Este é um comportamento esperado no Python em relação à realocação de recursos de uma lista.

Sempre que for feito a realocação de memória em uma lista, o Python irá alocar mais memória que realmente o necessário com a finalidade de evitar futuros realocamentos num futuro próximo - é mais simples você realocar n*X de memória uma vez e alterar a lista n vezes do que ter que realocar X de memória por n vezes.

Isso fica explícito em um comentário na função [`list_resize`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Objects/listobject.c#L42), no repositório oficial:

```c
/* This over-allocates proportional to the list size, making room
 * for additional growth.  The over-allocation is mild, but is
 * enough to give linear-time amortized behavior over a long
 * sequence of appends() in the presence of a poorly-performing
 * system realloc().
 * The growth pattern is:  0, 4, 8, 16, 25, 35, 46, 58, 72, 88, ...
 */
new_allocated = (newsize >> 3) + (newsize < 9 ? 3 : 6);
```

Ou seja, o tamanho de memória que será realocado para a lista será proporcional ao seu tamanho atual. Isso fica evidente quando você modifica uma lista dentro de um laço de repetição e verifica o seu tamanho atual:

```
import sys

lista = []

for _ in range(20):
    print('Lista de tamanho {:>3} com memória {:>3}'.format(len(lista), sys.getsizeof(lista)))
    lista.append(None)
```

O resultado será:

```
Lista de tamanho   0 com memória  64
Lista de tamanho   1 com memória  96
Lista de tamanho   2 com memória  96
Lista de tamanho   3 com memória  96
Lista de tamanho   4 com memória  96
Lista de tamanho   5 com memória 128
Lista de tamanho   6 com memória 128
Lista de tamanho   7 com memória 128
Lista de tamanho   8 com memória 128
Lista de tamanho   9 com memória 192
Lista de tamanho  10 com memória 192
Lista de tamanho  11 com memória 192
Lista de tamanho  12 com memória 192
Lista de tamanho  13 com memória 192
Lista de tamanho  14 com memória 192
Lista de tamanho  15 com memória 192
Lista de tamanho  16 com memória 192
Lista de tamanho  17 com memória 264
Lista de tamanho  18 com memória 264
Lista de tamanho  19 com memória 264
```

> **Nota:** perceba que para este exemplo eu modifiquei a lista a partir do método `append`. Ou seja, este comportamento é esperado para qualquer realocação de recurso da lista, independente da fonte desta realocação.

Ao passo que consegue-se amortizar o tempo de realocação de recursos em uma lista - que pode ser benéfico para a performance da aplicação - há contratempos em questão de utilização do recursos.

Se você possui uma lista com 16 valores, `None`, e precisar adicionar outro, sua lista passará a consumir 264 bytes na memória ao invés de apenas 200, que seria o necessário - mas, lembre-se, é Python. Você acabará abrindo mão de alguns requisitos para conseguir obter outros.

Comment: Nem vi que se tinha respondido, lol...

Comment: @MagicHat foi praticamente junto xD

Comment: Vou ver se menciono algo relevante que não tenha mencionado ai posto denovo...hehe