# Utilização de Append - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Qual a necessidade de usar a função "Append" no meu código? Dizem que ele pode ser utilizado para adicionar outro elemento na minha lista Python, porém não seria mais simples eu adicionar esse outro elemento de forma tradicional? O Append só serve para essa "adição"?

Comment: Qual seria a "forma tradicional"?

Comment: Apenas escrevendo o elemento junto com os outros que fazem parte.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adicionar um elemento em uma lista de forma dinâmica e existem diversas razões para isso ser possível:

- Não conhecer previamente o valor a ser adicionado;
- Garantir que sua lista tenha espaço para o novo valor;

E possivelmente outros motivos.

> Não conhecer previamente o valor a ser adicionado

Digamos que eu precise solicitar ao meu usuário uma lista com 5 valores inteiros. Como eu poderei criar essa lista se eu não sei quais os valores que o usuário digitará? Assim, eu preciso criar a minha lista e inserir os valores dinamicamente:

```
numeros = []

for _ in range(5):
    numeros.append(int(input('Digite um número: '))

print(numeros)
```

Com isso, não importa quais os valores que o usuário digitar, o programa irá adicionar na lista da mesma forma.

```
>>> Digite um número: 1
>>> Digite um número: 2
>>> Digite um número: 3
>>> Digite um número: 4
>>> Digite um número: 5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Isso significa que sempre utilizarei o `append`? Não. Muitos problemas podem ser resolvidos de outras maneiras. Cabe a você, como desenvolvedor, avaliar qual é a ideal. Se você quer uma lista com 5 valores lidos do usuário, poderia fazer:

```
numeros = [int(input('Digite um número: ')) for _ in range(5)]
```

O resultado é exatamente o mesmo que o anterior, sem utilizar o `append`. Se eu quero apenas os valores pares, como citado na outra resposta, você poderia fazer:

```
pares = [numero for numero in range(20) if numero % 2 == 0]
```

Mesmo resultado sem utilizar o `append`.

Inclusive, muitas vezes é mais viável você fazer **sem o `append`**, pois ele gasta memória a toa.

> Garantir que sua lista tenha espaço para o novo valor

Se a minha lista possui 5 elementos, ela ocupará em memória o equivalente a 5 vezes a memória que é demandada por aquele tipo de objeto. Se eu necessito adicionar um sexto elemento na lista, o que me garante que existe memória disponível? O método `append` irá garantir isso para você pois ele realizará o que chamamos de alocação dinâmica da memória. Sempre que for inserir um novo elemento ele ficará responsável por alocar memória para que seja possível guardar o novo valor.

Essa alocação dinâmica do `append`, inclusive, busca funcionar de uma forma otimizada. Como fazer a alocação de memória para cada novo valor pode ser custoso para aplicação, ao invés de alocar apenas um novo espaço serão alocados vários, para caso seja adicionados mais valores já exista memória disponível. Isso é interessante se a sua lista sofre muitas modificações, mas é ruim em casos contrários, pois pode ser alocado muito mais memória do que realmente era necessário.

Eu comentei sobre esse comportamento em:

- [Por que essas duas formas de inicializar a mesma lista em Python geram estruturas de tamanhos diferentes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/319164/5878)

Por esse motivo é comum você ler que é melhor você utilizar a *list-comprehension* (soluções acima sem o `append`) do que as soluções que usam o `append`. Porém nem sempre isso é válido; há problemas que é melhor utilizar o `append` - senão ele nem existiria.

Answer (score 2):

É recomendado usar o *append* quando você utiliza um laço para gravar esses dados em uma lista, exemplo:
Neste exemplo quero apenas os números pares de 0 até 20

```
lista_par = []
for i in range(20):
   if i%2 == 0:
      lista_par.append(i)
print(lista_par)
```

Saida = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]

Comment: Quem recomenda? Por que é recomendado?

Comment: Quando você utiliza o sinal de atribuição você sobrescreve o objeto, quando você utiliza o  *append* você adiciona o elemento no final da lista, o controle de índice é realizada automaticamente, já quando você utiliza apenas o sinal de atribuição simples, o igual "=" , você que deverá realizar este controle, adicionando um indicie e incrementando, no exemplo a cima caso utilize o "=" ficaria assim "lista_par[i] = i" dentro do bloco for.

Comment: A resposta não está errada, mas me senti obrigado a votar contra por achar que falta embasamento. Se você editar a resposta e complementar com os argumentos que defendem a sua resposta, terei o prazer de reconsiderar o voto. Nos comentários você até cita alguns motivos, então isso deveria estar na resposta. Seria interessante explicar também porque sobrescrever o objeto é pior que alterá-lo. Sempre isso é verdade?

Comment: Eu sou novo aqui no stack overflow com um dos que ajuda a solucionar dúvidas, ainda estou pegando a manha de explicar as coisas, principalmente programação. Obrigado pelo feedback, vou melhorar e da próxima vez  espero fazer corretamente!

Comment: Seja bem-vindo, então :D Qualquer coisa, sempre estamos online no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) da comunidade caso queira tirar alguma dúvida.

Comment: Muito obrigado !