# Comparação entre Dicionário e Lista

Tags: python, lista, comparação, dicionário

Eu estou fazendo um programa em que a ideia é começar perguntando se a pessoa já é cadastrada, caso contrário, ela passa por um. Eu estou tento problemas em verificar se o nome de usuário já é existente, por base de uma lista de usuários, a ideia é que se o nome já estiver na lista de usuários cadastrados, esse nome não possa ser cadastrado novamente. As linhas em conflito estão com comentário de "ERRO". Eis o código:

```
#  Arquivo de usuários CADASTRADOS
usuarios = list({'nome': 'marcelo', 'senha': 'marcelo123'})
usuario = dict()


#  Função de CADASTRAR
def cadastro():
    global usuarios
    global usuario
    while True:
        usuario.clear()
        usuario['nome'] = str(input('Digite o nome de usuário que deseja ter: '))
#  A LINHA ABAIXO DA ERRO!
        if usuario['nome'] not in usuarios['nome']:
            break
        print('Nome de usuário já existente! Por favor, tente outro nome de usuário.')
    usuario['senha'] = str(input('Digite a senha que deseja ter: '))
    usuarios.append(usuario.copy)
    print(usuario)


#  O usuário tem CADASTRO?
while True:
    temcadastro = str(input('Você já está cadastrado?[Sim/Não]: ')).upper().strip()[0]
    if temcadastro in 'SN':
        break
    print('Por favor, responda somente com Sim ou Não.')
if temcadastro == 'N':
#  A LINHA ABAIXO DA ERRO!
    cadastro()
print('Fim do programa (por enquanto).')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`usuarios` é uma **lista de dicionários**, e não um dicionário. Portanto, a sintaxe `usuarios['nome']` falhará.

Para obter os nomes dos usuários, você terá de **iterar sobre esta lista** e coletar o valor associado à chave `'nome'` de cada dicionário dentro dela:

```
usuarios_existentes = []
for user in usuarios:
    usuarios_existentes.append(user['nome'])
if usuario['nome'] not in usuarios_existentes:
    # . . .
```

(usei a variável `user` em inglês para diferenciá-la da sua variável `usuario`)

Ou, como é comum em Python, utilizar uma **compreensão de lista** para fazer esta mesma operação em uma linha:

```
usuarios_existentes = [user['nome'] for user in usuarios]
if usuario['nome'] not in usuarios_existentes:
    # . . .
```

Comment: Só para lembrar que a operação `in` é mais performática quando aplica a _sets_ (O(1)) do que em _lists_ (O(n)). Então você poderia só trocar por `usuarios_existentes = {user['nome'] for user in usuarios}` caso sua lista de usuários seja muito grande. ;)

Comment: PS: Não acho que deva adicionar isso na resposta, é só para deixar uma observação para futuros visitantes.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Troque:

```
usuarios = list({'nome': 'marcelo', 'senha': 'marcelo123'})

# por:

usuarios = [{'nome': 'marcelo', 'senha': 'marcelo123'}]
```

E:

```
if usuario['nome'] not in usuarios['nome']:

# por:

if usuario['nome'] not in {u['nome'] for u in usuarios}:
```

---

Parece que você ainda não entende bem como usar as estruturas de dados do python. Vou tentar explicar o que acho que você ainda não entende.

## Criação de lista de dicionários

Seu código:

```
usuarios = list({'nome': 'marcelo', 'senha': 'marcelo123'})
```

O conteúdo de `usuarios` agora é `['nome', 'senha']`, e não é o que você esperava. Para entender o motivo precisamos entender o que `list()` faz.

A [documentação de `list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-list) mostra que `list` recebe um iterável como parâmetro, então você poderia passar qualquer iterável que `list()` fará a iteração sobre o argumento recebido e adicionará cada item dessa iteração na nova lista criada.

Para fins didáticos, seria como:

```
def list(iteravel):
    nova_lista = []  # cria a nova lista

    for item in iteravel:
       nova_lista.append(item)  # adiciona o item à nova lista

    return nova_lista  # retorna a nova lista criada
```

Sabendo disso, voltamos para o seu código. Você está passado um dicionário para `list()`, como dicionários são iteráveis está tudo bem, porém quando você itera sobre um dicionário, você itera sobre suas chaves. Na [documentação de `dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) você verá que chamar `iter(d)` é apenas um atalho para `iter(d.keys)`. Exemplo:

```
dicionario = {
    'chave_1': 'Valor 1',
    'chave_2': 'Valor 2',
    'chave_3': 'Valor 3',
}

for item in dicionario:
    print(item)

# chave_1
# chave_2
# chave_3
```

Então seu código:

```
usuarios = list({'nome': 'marcelo', 'senha': 'marcelo123'})
```

Seria como você estivesse fazendo:

```
usuario = []

for chave in {'nome': 'marcelo', 'senha': 'marcelo123'}:
    usuario.append(chave)

# usuario = ['nome', 'senha']
```

O que você realmente quer é uma lista de dicionários, onde cada dicionário corresponde a um usuário do seu sistema. Para isso bastaria fazer:

```
usuarios = [{'nome': 'marcelo', 'senha': 'marcelo123'}]
```

---

## Checagem de existência de usuário

A checagem de existência de um usuário no seu sistema vai depender da estrutura usada para guardar seus usuário.

Vou tomar como verdade que você corrigiu seu código e está usando uma lista de dicionários, como a sessão anterior da resposta explicou.

O operador `in`, quando [utilizado em sequências](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) testa se algum item na lista tem valor igual ao item procurado. Ou seja, `1 in [0, 1, 2]` seria como testar:

```
def contem(valor, sequencia):
    for item in sequencia:
        if item == valor
            return True
    return False

contem(1, [0, 1, 2])  # True
contem(5, [0, 1, 2])  # False
```

Explico isto porque se você olhar a [documentação do dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) verá que diz:

> Dictionaries compare equal if and only if they have the same (key, value) pairs (regardless of ordering).

Tradução livre:

> Dicionários são tratados como iguais em uma comparação se, e somente se, eles tem os mesmo pares de chave e valor (independente de sua ordem).

Ou seja, se você testar se `dict_a == dict_b` o resultado será baseado em suas chaves e valores, mesmo que referenciem a objetos distintos em memória (minha resposta e a resposta aceita [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/418089/6333) explicam um pouco mais sobre isso). Então:

```
dict_1 = {'chave_1': 1, 'chave_2': 2}
dict_2 = {'chave_2': 2, 'chave_1': 1}

dict_1 == dict_2
# True

dict_1 is dict_2
id(dict_1) == id(dict_2)
# False para ambos (mesmo valor, mas objetos diferentes)
```

Moral da história, se você testar seu objeto diretamente na lista de usuários só funcionará se seu objeto também tiver a chave `senha` como valor correto na listagem.

```
usuarios = list({'nome': 'marcelo', 'senha': 'marcelo123'})

'marcelo' in usuarios
# False

{'nome': 'marcelo'} in usuarios
# False

{'nome': 'marcelo', 'senha': 'marcelo123'} in usuarios
# True
```

Uma boa saída é criar um `set()` com os nomes já cadastrados e testar a existência neste `set()`. Seu código ficaria assim:

```
cadastros = {u['nome'] for u in usuarios}
if usuario['nome'] not in cadastros:
    break
```

Você pode ver mais sobre [`set()` e *set comprehension* na documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehension#sets).