# Quebrar string a cada 4 posições - Python

Tags: python, string

Considerando que temos a seguinte string.

```
codigo = '7777. 5698 897897. 236'
```

Após a remoção dos espaços e .

```
codigo_formatado = ''.join(codigo_de_barras.split()).replace(".", "")
codigo_formatado
```

**Saída**

```
'77775698897897236'
```

Como faço para quebrar a string '77775698897897236' considerando a contagem de 4 em 4 posições para que a saída seja semelhante abaixo:

```
7777
5698
8978
9723
6
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acho que um simples laço for é simples e efetivo o bastante, não?

```
codigo = '77775698897897236'

for i in range(0, len(codigo), 4):
    print(str[i:i+4])
```

Se precisa da resposta numa lista, basta fazer o append.

Comment: A sua sugestão está dando erro

Comment: Eu usei uma vírgula para separar os índices, deveria ser dois pontos.

Comment: Editei a resposta só porque a variável `str` estava sobrescrevendo a string nativa do python e os espaço no _slice_ pra ficar em conformidade com o PEP8. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Na [sessão "receitas"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) do módulo [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) tem uma função chamada `grouper` que pega uma sequência e itera "aos pedaços":

```py
from itertools import zip_longest


def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)


teste = "77775698897897236"

for grupo in grouper(teste, 4, ''):
    print("".join(grupo))
```

<sup>*[Código rodando no Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOP-427801-6333)*</sup>

Resultado:

```
7777
5698
8978
9723
6
```

### Edit

A [resposta que usa *slicing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/427805/6333) é perfeitamente cabível para casos onde o iterável é pequeno, minha resposta se torna mais efetiva caso você esteja trabalhando com sequência muito maiores pois não há cópia de partes do iterável e também funcionaria ao receber qualquer iterável, mesmo que este não suporte *slicing*.

---

## Explicação

Começando com a linha:

```
args = [iter(iterable)] * n
```

Primeiramente:

1. Criamos um objeto do tipo `Iterator` usando o método [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter);
2. Uma lista com um único elemento é criada, este elemento é o iterador criado no item acima;
3. Multiplicamos a lista `n` vezes para que sejam criadas `n` referências **ao mesmo iterador** ([nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/418089/6333) explico melhor sobre multiplicação de sequências).

   ```
   >>> [iter("77775698897897236")] * 4
   [<str_iterator at 0x7f07473b4f10>,
    <str_iterator at 0x7f07473b4f10>,
    <str_iterator at 0x7f07473b4f10>,
    <str_iterator at 0x7f07473b4f10>]
   ```

Como você pode perceber no item 3, temos uma lista com 4 referências ao mesmo iterador, pois os quatro apontam para o mesmo endereço de memória (`0x7f07473b4f10`).

Ou seja, se eu consumir 1 item de cada referência seria o mesmo que consumir 4 itens do iterador "original".

```
>>> for iterador in [iter("1234567890")] * 4:
>>>     next(iterador)
1
2
3
4
```

É aí que entra o [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest), para consumir estas referências ao mesmo iterador. Pois quando você faz:

```
args = [iter("1234567890")] * 4
zip_longest(*args)
```

Seria o mesmo que fazer:

```
ref_iter = iter("1234567890")
zip_longest(ref_iter, ref_iter, ref_iter, ref_iter)
```

E na prática este código consome todo o iterador de 4 em 4 itens. O código acima retornaria:

```
>>> ref_iter = iter("1234567890")
>>> zip_longest(ref_iter, ref_iter, ref_iter, ref_iter)
[('1', '2', '3', '4'), ('5', '6', '7', '8'), ('9', '0', None, None)]
```

Answer (score -2):

Adapta a seu código

```
    print([codigo[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(codigo), 4)])
```

Comment: Nelson, você só copiou a resposta aceita e transformou o for em _list comprehension_.
Não tem nada que você possa acrescentar que as outras resposta ainda não abordaram?

Comment: @fernandosavio não foi minha intensão "copiar " o seu código, até porque sua resposta é encontrada em outros sites, basta pesquisar no google.

Creio que é a forma mais simples de resolver o problema acima, por isso nada mais tenho a acrescentar

Comment: Meu comentário não foi por causa de autoria de código, mas sim porque sua resposta não acrescentou nada ao que já havia nas outras respostas. Tem algo que diferencie sua resposta das outras? Algo que o autor da pergunta possa aprender que já não foi explicado em outras respostas? Entende meu ponto?