# Lista salvando valores do último laço utilizando random em todas as posições

Tags: python

Gente, to tentando criar uma lista com valores aleatórios dentro de outras listas predefinidas. Aí no laço ele me retorna certinho 10 linhas com 4 dados com valores diferentes. Mas quando sai do laço e eu mando um print em todas as linhas salvou apenas os valores aleatórios do ultimo laço em todos os índices.

```
numbers = 10
x_tes2 = [[0,0,0,0]]*numbers


for key in range(0,numbers):
    x_tes2[key][0]=int(random.choice(year))
    x_tes2[key][1]=int(random.choice(km_driven))
    x_tes2[key][2]=str(random.choice(fuel))
    x_tes2[key][3]=str(random.choice(transmission))

    print(x_tes2[key][0:4])
print("\n")
print(x_tes2)
```

O output:
[image: Output]

Alguém sabe o porquê?

Comment: Quando fez isso `x_tes2 = [[0,0,0,0]]*numbers`  fez com que todos os elementos do array `x_tes2` referencie o mesmo array `[0,0,0,0]`.

Comment: Se estiver com dúvidas de como funciona multiplicação de listas em python tenho [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/418089/6333) que escrevi há um tempo que tenta explicar melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que quando você cria um array da forma `x_tes2 = [[0,0,0,0]]*numbers` você está multiplicando a mesma lista, copiando e colando ela várias vezes. Dessa forma, quando você alterar qualquer um dos arrays todos serão alterados, porque todas se referenciam à mesma lista.

A melhor maneira para você chegar ao resultado é criar um array vazio, preencher a lista no laço *for* e adicionar essa lista ao array principal, algo como isso:

```
numbers = 10
x_tes2 = []
for key in range(0, numbers):
    random_array = [int(random.choice(year)), int(random.choice(km_driven)), str(random.choice(fuel)), str(random.choice(transmission))]
    x_tes2.append(random_array)
```